# Array-like operations with Multiindex in Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, multi-index

I have a pivot table with a multiindex, with one of the levels being the 'field' (what the data actually are) and one being, conceptually, the actual index. I would like to do some transformations on the data, e.g. take the natural log, and add the transformed values as a set of rows. For example:

```
      col   1   2   3   4 ... 100
field idx   
foo   A     7   9   2   5 ... 47
      B     8   3   4   8 ... 82
      C     3   6   1   9 ... 23
bar   A     1   17  5   2 ... 32
      B     7   5   4   8 ... 78
      C     28  6   11  3 ... 11
```

Should become:

```
      col   1   2   3   4 ... 100
field idx   
foo   A     7   9   2   5 ... 47
      B     8   3   4   8 ... 82
      C     3   6   1   9 ... 23
bar   A     1   17  5   2 ... 32
      B     7   5   4   8 ... 78
      C     28  6   11  3 ... 11
lnfoo A     <element-wise>
      B     <natural logs>
      C     <of foo>
```

Is there an easy way to do this sort of array-wide operation on a multiindex pivot table like this? Particularly without needing to iterate over rows of the dataframe?

Pretty new to Pandas so sorry if it's a silly question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply the log to the full foo index level, you can select all the rows at once with `loc` and use `np.log` to do the example operation.

```
#example data
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,50,30).reshape(6,-1), 
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['foo','bar'], list("ABC")], 
                                                   names=['field', 'idx']))

print(np.log(df.loc['foo']))
            0         1         2         3         4
idx                                                  
A    2.302585  3.610918  2.772589  0.000000  3.367296
B    3.258097  3.401197  3.891820  3.401197  2.197225
C    2.302585  0.000000  3.761200  3.713572  3.610918
```

As you can see, the level field is not in the result and you need to recreate this level, using `pd.concat` with a dictionary and the names of the level to create. Then use again `pd.concat` to add it at the end of df.

```
df = pd.concat([df, 
                pd.concat({'logfoo': np.log(df.loc['foo'])}, 
                          names=['field'])
               ])
print(df)
                    0          1          2          3          4
field  idx                                                       
foo    A    10.000000  37.000000  16.000000   1.000000  29.000000
       B    26.000000  30.000000  49.000000  30.000000   9.000000
       C    10.000000   1.000000  43.000000  41.000000  37.000000
bar    A    17.000000  37.000000  48.000000  12.000000  25.000000
       B    44.000000  34.000000   9.000000  37.000000  15.000000
       C    14.000000   6.000000  14.000000  26.000000  14.000000
logfoo A     2.302585   3.610918   2.772589   0.000000   3.367296
       B     3.258097   3.401197   3.891820   3.401197   2.197225
       C     2.302585   0.000000   3.761200   3.713572   3.610918
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben.T, I will try that! Why are there two `pd.concat` calls?

Comment: @TYLim As I said in the short text in the middle, doing `np.log(df.loc['foo'])` you loose a level, so `pd.concat({'logfoo': np.log(df.loc['foo'])}, names=['field'])` is just an easy way to prepend a level of index. moreover, you can easily add different transformation in the dictionary like `pd.concat({'logfoo': np.log(df.loc['foo']), 'expbar':np.exp(df.loc['bar'])}, names=['field'])`. the outer concat is just to have df and the transformed values in a same dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
tmp = df.query('field == "foo"').rename(index={'foo': 'lnfoo'})
pd.concat([df, np.log(tmp)])
```

You can easily extend this to cover `bar` as well:

```
tmp = df.query('field in ("foo", "bar")').rename(index={'foo': 'lnfoo', 'bar': 'lnbar'})
pd.concat([df, np.log(tmp)])
```